# how to affect foreach items style (hover) every item alone

Tags: jquery, css, razor, asp.net-core

I used `foreach` statement to access all items of `IEnumerable` and present it in details page. I want to make hover property of each item affect only one item. So I used jQuery to affects on each item alone

But when I run the code and hover on one item then all items affect with the hovering property at the same time.

How to affects on each item alone ?

Here is my Tag Helper :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TimeLines)
{
    <section id="timeline">
        <article>
            <div class="inner">
                <span class="date">
                    <span class="day">@item.EventDate</span>
                </span>
                <h2>@item.Title</h2>
                <h5>@Html.Raw(item.Body)</h5>
                <div class="form-group row col-lg-12">
                    @if (User.IsInRole("Admins") || Model.TimeLineCategory.ApplicationUserId == currentUser.Id)
                    {
                        @*<div class="button_cont row col-lg-6" align="center"><a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="TimeLines" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="example_c" noopener">Edit</a></div>*@
                        <div class="button_cont row col-lg-6" align="center"><a asp-controller="TimeLines" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="cursor:pointer;" class="example_c" id="del">حذف</a></div>
                        <div class="button_cont row col-lg-6" align="center"><a asp-controller="TimeLines" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" style="cursor:pointer;" class="example_c">تعديل</a></div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
}
```

and my jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $('section article').each(function (i, element) {
        $("div.inner .form-group").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $('.example_c').show();
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $('.example_c').hide();
            }
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search the specific child element of the element that you hovered, in that way you can display only the element that you want...
the $(this) element refers to the element that you hovered.

```
$('section article').each(function (i, element) {
    $("div.inner .form-group").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find('.example_c').show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).find('.example_c').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what about the id of section element in foreach loop? doesn't it look weird to you?

Comment: You could simplify that even more :
`$('section article').each(function (i, element) {
    $("div.inner .form-group").on('hover', function() {
        $(this).find('.example_c').toggle();
    });
});`